# Mac Encoding issue for third party screen recording app?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, intel

I am using a Mac app that I had made for me and have been using for almost 2 years now with no issues. but recently I got a 2019 MacBook Pro and have been having issue with saving the screen recordings once done where the videos get saved but the video length much longer than the actual length and there are these lines under the duration line of the video if anyone could tell me what this means and possibly what the issue might be that would be appreciated [image: close up of the duration bar with odd lines underneath]

Answer (score 1):

The recording was made at a frame rate higher than 60 fps and regarded as a slow motion video, such as that would be taken on an iPhone. The default behaviour is to slow down the middle part of the video, which is shown and adjustable by the second bar below the seek bar.

Comment: okay so you're saying the app is recording at a higher frame rate then this Mac can handle? and how do I fix that?